# PDF Media Upload with Wordpress

Tags: pdf, wordpress, upload, media

I have a WP installation on IIS that won't let me upload a PDF to the media section, but it has the following weirdness:

- I can upload a smaller PDF (~22KB)
- Can't upload the larger one (~4.2MB), even though my upload limit is 64MB.
- I can upload images
- I can zip the large PDF to ~4.1MB and upload the zip file
- Trying to upload the large PDF gives ... mydomain.com didn't send any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome
- There are no error messages in the webserver or the PHP log files
- I've checked the permissions are correct on the WP content folder and the temp upload folder (on the server)

I don't know what to try next....any ideas on getting useful errors out of a webserver / browser?

Comment: Further investigation shows that this seems to be related to large (ish) PDF files - they won't upload, whereas large (ish) ZIP files (for instances) will.

Comment: And it works in Firefox...?